# How to fetch list of hyperlink on webpage based on only the image color corresponding to these hyperlinks?

Tags: css, image, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, background-color

I need to fetch the list of hyperlinks on a webpage having red/green color bullets against them using Selenium Webdriver. Is it possible? These hyperlinks are dynamically generated based on IP provided by user.
For ex, When user access http://www.dnsbl.info/ , and enter any specific IP address, I need to fetch a list of hyperlinks having green color and another list containing hyperlinks with red color. Can this scenario be automated using webdriver?

Below listed is my script as of now :

```
public class SelectCategory extends Config {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test(enabled = true)

    public void Blacklist1() throws IOException {

        Properties p = new Properties(GetDataFromFile());

        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(p.getProperty("BLURL"));

        WebElement D1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='quickcheck']/input[1]"));
        D1.clear();
        D1.sendKeys(p.getProperty("IP1"));

        WebElement D2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='quickcheck']/input[2]"));
        D2.click();

    }

    public Properties GetDataFromFile() throws IOException {
        File F = new File("*Path of properties file");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(F);
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(fis);
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean these hyperlinks have different colors? can you show how exactly do they look on web or a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve that issue, which is not efficient in my opinion, is to save the img src links of each IP (by scraping them) and then click on each img src link one by one.

Each time after you click you will need to know what your current url is (that is how you will now the color of the IP. 
Here is an example, this is the element of one of the IP color balls:

```
<img height="15" width="15" src="http://www1.dnsbl.info/test-a.php?bl=bl.emailbasura.org&ip=208.87.233.201&cb=1123477419&token=0f46ad74b3eb0606dc4644be7218d0d5" alt="">
```

You basically need to parse the link inside the variable src.

A green image will have its url like this: http://www.dnsbl.info/images/ball_green_15x15.gif
Any url other than this is not considered green.